# Move Textview around limited screen android

Tags: android

Hi i have implemented code of moving textview around whole screen it working fine for whole screen
but right now i want to implement it around limited screen

suppose there is relative layout of 200dp height and 200 width, in that there is one textview and one imageview

**like below**

```
        --RelativeLayout
                --ImageView
                --TextView
```

but textview is not going move properly it will disappear fast, like it is moving more

below is my **code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and javacode is below

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView txtHour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHour);
    txtHour.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            drag(event, v);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void drag(MotionEvent event, View v)
 {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

     switch(event.getAction())
     {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
          params.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
          params.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
          v.setLayoutParams(params);
          break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
          params.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
          params.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
          v.setLayoutParams(params);
          break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
         v.setLayoutParams(params);
         break;
        }
     }
 }
}
```

can any body tell me how to move it in limited area as my finger move on that area?